# creating a delay promise using promises

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I have a js promise question but it is giving me errors

```
function delay(n) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, n*1000));
}
```

This is supposed to say it is now 2 seconds later and then is is now 1.5 seconds later but it says

> It is now undefined later
> It is now undefined later

```
delay(2)
    .then(seconds => console.log(`It is now ${seconds} later`))
    .then(() => delay(1.5))
    .then(seconds => console.log(`It is now ${seconds} later`));
```

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't passing any value to `resolve`, so the resolved value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including a resolve value; change `setTimeout(resolve` to `setTimeout(function() {resolve(n);}`.

Comment: The core issue is that OP's code is not including a resolve value.

Comment: Protip: `setTimeout(resolve, n * 1000, n)`…

Comment: My issue is that this is not waiting that amount of seconds to print. Like with the first .thenm it should wait 2 seconds to print that message and then 1.5 for the next one and Idk where to add that delay because doing *1000 inside the resolve or after doesnt work

Comment: @Christian `return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n * 1000, n))`. This. This works. If it doesn't, you'll need to show your actual code. The code in your question should already be delaying correctly, you're simply not passing the value of `n` through. This answer fixes that.

Answer (score -1):

[`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) accepts multiple parameters;

```
setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)
```

So after you've set the second `setTimeout` paramter to the milliseconds you want to wait, you can pass any additional parameters;

So change

```
setTimeout(resolve, n*1000)
```

To

```
setTimeout(resolve, n*1000, n)
```

```js
function delay(n) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, n*1000, n));
}
delay(2)
    .then(seconds => console.log(`It is now ${seconds} seconds later`))
    .then(() => delay(5))
    .then(seconds => console.log(`It is now ${seconds} seconds later`));
```

Comment: Refactored my answer for the records.